# Jquery $.each through array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using this code to loop through an array and call a function `doAjax()` for each `value`:

```
$.each(categories, function(index, value){
        doAjax(value);
});
```

The function `doAjax()` will make a Ajax call and append some data to an html page. The problem is that when I loop through large array (10+ indexes) it is causing my website to crash.

The only way I can think to solve this problem is to make listener to the page like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 50){
        //code to trigger function goes here
    }
});
```

so when the user scroll to the bottom of the page it will load more stuff.

So I want to make my `$.each` only call `doAjax()` 3 or 4 times. The problem I ran into is that its calling the same values from the array so I made a temporarily variable and stored my original array in it like so:

```
var temp = categories;
```

and then every time `$.each` runs, I delete the value from the temp array.

I know this is not he best way to do stuff, but this what I was able to think of.

If you can suggest a better way to solve this problem that will be appreciated. Otherwise I want my $.each to run at least once (and loop through 3 or 4 elements only) when the doc loads, then delete the array elements that it already went through, then run again (only through 3 or 4 elements)when the user scroll to the bottom of the page until there is no more elements in the temp array..

Comment: Why cant you pass all the category values in a single result and get response as json?

Comment: I am using google search api. and I want to make one call per item.

Comment: likely need to throttle the code running in `scroll` handler. Keep in mind `scroll` event will fire many times a second while user is moving scrollbar

Comment: I think I can solve this problem by making a var and set it to true or false and then just check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop and remove the categories array try,

```
function sendAjax(cat) {
    if(cat.length>1){
     var len = ( cat.length > 3 )  ? 3 : cat.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { //send ajax 3 times
        if (typeof cat[i] != "undefined") {
           // doAjax(cat[i]);
        }
     }
    }
    cat = cat.splice(len);//remove the first three elements from array
    return cat;  
}
```

Comment: would this work ? `categories = sendAjax(categories );`

Answer (score 0):

how about appending all the results of your array => doAjax function, then once its all done, then append to your page.. ala

this might work for reducing the array:

```
var arr2 = categories.splice(0); // copy the original categories array to a new array
var rotationNum = 3;
function sendIt(){
   var lngth = (arr2.length < rotationNum) ? arr2.length : rotationNum; 
   for (var i = 0; i < lngth ; i++){
    //doAjax
   }
   arr2.splice(0,lngth);
}
```

or try below to store up all the ajax calls, then append.

```
var categoriesDeferred = [];

for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
  categoriesDeferred.push(doAjax(categories[i]));
}

$.when.apply($, categoriesDeferred).then(everythingDoneFunc); 

function doAjax(data) {
  var dferred = $.Deferred();    
  //your ajax call here.. .
  setTimeout(function() { dferred.resolve() }, 2000);    

  return dferred.promise();
}

function everythingDoneFunc(){
  console.log('everything processeed');
}
```